# Clarification of References in C++

Tags: c++, variables, reference

So I am attempting to learn C++ and I have come across something that puzzles me slightly. I have the code,

```
int x = 0;
int &y = x;
cout << &x<< " " << x << " " << &y << " " <<y<< endl;
```

This compiles fine and results in:

```
0 003AFA08 0 003AFA08
```

What I have trouble understanding why the conversion of x, an int, to &y, a reference, doesn't result in an error. At first I thought it was some sort of conversion however,

```
int &y = &x;
```

results in an error.

Can anyone explain why this works in this way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to know why the stream insertion operator `<<` can stringify the address of a variable as a numeric hex string but you can't assign the address of an `int` (with type `int *`) to `int &`?

Comment: I guess it's `003AFA08 0 003AFA08 0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`int&` is not an *address*.  It is a *reference*.

`int& y = x;` declares `y` as a reference to `x`.  It effectively means that `y` becomes another name for `x`.  Any time you use `y`, it is as if you had said `x`.

Pointers (not references) are used to store addresses.  `int& y = &x;` is not valid because `&x` is the address of `x` (it's an `int*`).  `y` is a reference to an `int`, not a reference to an `int*`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `&x` is not the *address of* `x`, but a *pointer to* `x`, even though the `&` operator is called *address-of* :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: "A valid value of an object pointer type represents either the address of a byte in memory or a null pointer." Close enough for me. :)

Comment: @GMan: "The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. [...] if the type of the expression is `T`, the result has type "pointer to `T`" and is a prvalue that is the address of the designated object."

Comment: @FredOverflow: "and is [...] the address of the designated object". So what's wrong with saying `&x` is the address of `x`?

Comment: @GMan: If it were *only* an address, you could not dereference it or do anything useful with it.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Eh, I didn't say it was *only* an address, just that it is an address as implied by it being a pointer to an object.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't a conversion. When you have a variable type of `T &` where `T` is some random type, you are basically saying "I'm declaring a name which is an alias for another name or possibly an anonymous value.". It's more like a `typedef` than a pointer.

References happen to often be implemented as addresses, but that isn't a good model for thinking about what they are.

In your example that you're puzzled by:

```
int * const &y = &x;
```

would work just fine. Then `y` becomes an alias for the temporary result of taking the address of `x`. Notice that it is a reference to a pointer. It has to be a reference to a constant pointer because it is a reference to a temporary value.